# Is Ra's al Ghul really immortal?

Tags: dc, batman

I am a fan of Batman and justice league. I know the history of Ra' al Ghul, and that he restores his power from the Lazarus Pit.

My Question is: **Does it make him immortal like Vandal Savage ? Or does he require the pit every time to restore his power?**

If one time bath makes him immortal, then - since in *Batman: Red-Hood* Robin also took a bath in it - Robin should also be a immortal, shouldn't he?

If he is not immortal, then why does he say he is in Batman Begins?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No he is not immortal. He requires the Lazarus Pit in order to restore himself to his prime. This enables him to cheat death but can still die, unlike Vandal Savage. He can technically come back from the dead if placed in the Lazarus Pit, such as Jason Todd, the Red Hood.

In the Batman Begins movie, he was merely referring to what Ra's al Ghul represents to being immortal. Not himself. The idea that the need for justice against corruption, to do what is right at any price, will forever exist. At least to my understanding.

Comment: Good answer! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks. I discovered this site after recently joining Stack Exchange from Stack Overflow. Now I can further express my geekiness and love for comics and other such things.

Comment: Just as a point of fact, sometimes "immortality" can refer to being able to live forever barring unforeseen physical trauma. For example most vampires are considered "immortal" but that does not mean that they cannot be killed. In that sense, one could say that he *is* immortal.

Comment: @NominSim : As Robert pointed out, though, all the Lazarus Pit does is restore vitality and/or reverse aging. After bathing in the pit and being restored, he then ages normally and is completely susceptible to disease or injury like any other person. All the pit does is "reset the clock", so to speak.